# What is the significance of the term "Ariel" in Isaiah 29:1?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 29:1

> Woe to you, Ariel, Ariel, the city where David settled! Add year to year and let your cycle of festivals go on.

I understood that it is poetic but are there other reasons that Isaiah is calling out "Ariel"?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and Help (below). I have up-voted your question +1. I have edited your question only to demonstrate to you how to highlight a quoted reference. Please feel free to roll back if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Too long for a comment :**

- **[Bible Hub](http://www.biblehub.com/commentaries/isaiah/29-1.htm)**
- **Bible Study Tools**

  - *[Geneva Study Bible](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/geneva-study-bible/isaiah/isaiah-29.html)*
  - *[Jamieson Fausset Brown](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/jamieson-fausset-brown/isaiah/isaiah-29.html)*
  - *[John Gill](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/gills-exposition-of-the-bible/isaiah-29-1.html)*
  - *[Matthew Henry](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/matthew-henry-complete/isaiah/29.html)*
- **[Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1760)**
- **[Jewish Virtual Library](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/ariel-2)**
- **[Study Light](http://www.studylight.org/commentary/isaiah/29-1.html)**